# Mac application created with pyinstaller doesn't work with arguments

Tags: macos, pyinstaller

My python code works fine in the console. It loads a given excel file and writes some data into it with openpyxl:

```
try:
    # process given excel file
    PLIK = sys.argv[1]
    process_the_file(PLIK) # my function
except IndexError:
    print('No file to process')
```

I want to make an application from the script that works on Mac systems. I try to use pyinstaller like this:

```
>>> pyi-makespec my_script.py --onedir --windowed --argv-emulation --icon logo.icns --osx-bundle-identifier com.comp.my.script --name The_Script
```

After creating .spec file I add there the Mac-required data:

```
info_plist={
    'NSPrincipalClass': 'NSApplication',
    'NSAppleScriptEnabled': False,
    'CFBundleDocumentTypes': [{
           'CFBundleTypeName': "XLSX input table document",
           'CFBundleTypeExtensions': [
                'xlsx',
           ],
           'CFBundleTypeRole': "Editor",
           'LSItemContentTypes': [
                'com.microsoft.excel.xls'
           ],
           'LSHandlerRank': 'Owner'
      }],
 }
```

And I run a command to create the application:

```
>>> pyinstaller The_Script.spec
```

Now I try to use the application with an example.xslx file. I click on the example.xlsx file to open it with The_Script.app, but it is not working - in the debug I see the message 'No file to process'. It's like my passed arguments are not seen by the app.
I debug like this:

```
>>> open dist/The_Script.app/Contents/MacOS/The_Script --args example.xlsx
```

I suppose I read all the docs and the internet and I have no more ideas what's wrong.

Environment:

```
macOS Sonoma 14.4
Python 3.9.6
pyinstaller 6.4.0
```